# R iGraph - how to color edges used in minimum spanning tree

Tags: r, if-statement, colors, igraph, minimum-spanning-tree

I would like to plot the solution of the minimum spanning tree(MST) by coloring the edges used in the solution.

```
library("igraph")
A = matrix(c(0, 23, 11, 5, 26, 22,23, 0, 9, 13, 30, 18,11, 9, 0, 9, 7, 29,5, 13, 9, 0, 15, 5,26, 30, 7, 15, 0, 9,22, 18, 29, 5, 9, 0), 
           nrow= 6 , ncol= 6  ,byrow = TRUE)  
g  <- graph.adjacency(A,weighted=TRUE, mode = c("undirected"))
plot(g,edge.label=round(E(g)$weight, 3))
```

[image]

If I use `mst()` package, I get the following solution

```
mst(g)
IGRAPH ac800ea U-W- 6 5 -- 
+ attr: weight (e/n)
+ edges from ac800ea:
[1] 1--4 2--3 3--5 4--6 5--6
```

I would like to plot `g` and color the edges used in the solution provided above. For instance, I can use the following code, however, it only prints the edges used. I would like to print all edges while distinguishing the edges used in the MST.

```
plot(mst(g),layout=layout.reingold.tilford,edge.label=E(mst(g))$weight)
```

[image]

I tried `E(g)$color <- ifelse(E(g) %in% mst(g), "black", "red")` however it did not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
left_join(
  get.data.frame(g),
  cbind(get.data.frame(mst(g)), color = "black")
) %>%
  mutate(color = replace_na(color, "red")) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
  plot(
    edge.label = E(.)$weight,
    edge.color = E(.)$color
  )
```

which gives

[image]